# Command Line : Concatenate multiple files by date

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, concatenation

I have got a plenty of .txt files in a directory. The directory also contains .png and some .pdf files. I have successfully concatenated .txt files using this command :

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
for /r %%f in (*.txt) do (
echo.
type "%%f"
)>> output.doc

GOTO :EOF
```

The above command was obtained from one of the online sites. This command will concatenate .txt files in alphabetical order. But i don't want it like that , i want it to be done by the date modified or created (modified is recommended). 
I have got a hint that the line

```dos
for /r %%f in(*.txt) do (
```

must be modified in order to concatenate by date.I'm new to this command line or batch scripting so i don't really know much about it. How should i do this .
Thanks everyone for the answers.

Sorry for not including this question in the first time.
I have got one more requirement based on another question that i asked previously([Question](https://superuser.com/questions/900591/command-line-concatenate-multiple-files-by-date)) i have got a batch file for concatenating .txt files and for adding two lines on top of every file (one for writing the file name without the extension and other for writing the date associated to the concatenated file).Can anyone please modify the below batch file to concatenate .txt files by the order of date-modified and to add the two lines on top of each file.

```dos
@echo off
SETLOCAL
for /r %%f in (*.txt) do (
echo File Name   : %%~nf 
FOR /f %%d IN ("%%~tf") DO echo Date        : %%d
echo.
type "%%f"
) >> output_text.doc

GOTO :EOF
```

Every problem solved final batch file :

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "root=%cd%"

>"output.doc" (
    for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%a in ('
        robocopy "%root%\." "%root%\." *.txt /l /s /is /ts /ndl /njh /njs /nc /ns 
        ^| sort 
    ') do (
     echo( %%~nc
     for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%d in ("%%a") do echo %%f/%%e/%%d
     type "%%~fc"
    )
)
```

Comment: Do you actually need/want to recurse into subdirs (as the command shown would do)?

Comment: @wmz yeah ..And i want the process to be done in the order of date modified from oldest to new .

Comment: that's difficult in 'pure' batch (because of how cmd [mis]treats dates). Would you accept powershell solution?

Comment: @wmz I'll accept only requirement is i should get everything done .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "root=%cd%"

    >"output.doc" (
        for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('
            robocopy "%root%\." "%root%\." *.txt /l /s /is /ts /ndl /njh /njs /nc /ns 
            ^| sort 
        ') do type "%%~fb"
    )
```

This will use `robocopy` to get the list of all the `.txt` files under the indicated root folder.

The list of files is generated including the last modified date of the files. `robocopy` prints the UTC time in `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss` format, so the list can be properly sorted.

The rest of the code is just a `for /f` command to process the final list, retrieving the file reference and typing it. The full command is redirected to the output file to avoid the open/close operation for each processed file.

**edited** as it is needed to include the file name and the timestamp in the final output ...

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "root=%cd%"

    >"output.doc" (
        for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%a in ('
            robocopy "%root%\." "%root%\." *.txt /l /s /is /ts /ndl /njh /njs /nc /ns 
            ^| sort 
        ') do (
            echo(%%~nc
            echo(%%a %%b [%%~tc]
            type "%%~fc"
        )
    )
```

The `tokens` clause has been changed to retrieve the timestamp from `robocopy` so we can include it in the output. `%%a` will hold the date, `%%b` the time and `%%c` the file name with full path.

For each file, it is first echoed the file name without extension (`%%~nc`), then the `robocopy` time stamp and, just to compare as the output of robocopy is a UTC time, the file timestamp (`%%~tc`). Then the file is typed.

As before, all the output is redirected to the final file.

Comment: Please see my modified question.

Comment: @manutd, answer updated.

Comment: @MC_ND I only used the %%a for writing the date.But the problem is that it is displaying it in yyyy/mm/dd format i want it in dd/mm/yyyy format . How should i do this. I have this command with me :  FOR /f %%d IN ("%%~tf") DO echo Date        : %%d and this successfully prints date in dd-mm-yyyy format but the code doesn't work with the script you have provided .

Comment: @manutd, change your `echo(%%a` into `for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%d in ("%%a") do echo %%f/%%e/%%d`, that is, tokenize the data using the slash as delimiter and output the elements in reversed order

Answer (score 2):

Powershell (3 -see note) one liner:

`` gci *.txt -Recurse -File |sort -Property LastWriteTime |% {(gc $_) + "`n"} >output.doc ``

- It first lists all matching files (`gci`)
- then sorts them by modified date (`sort`)
- then gets contents of file and appends a newline to each (`gc`)
- and finally writes all to output file.

*Note: Because it uses `-File` which was introduced in ps3. This can be rewritten in Ps2 syntax, but it's more verbose.*

**Edit:** as requested by OP: modify {(gc $_) + "`n"}
to read:

`` {"$($_.basename)`n$(get-date -u %d/%m/%Y $_.lastwritetime)`n$(gc $_)`n"} ``

---

*(string interpolation used this time to show various options)*

*Side note: [possible] file encoding inconsistencies & problems not    handled.*

---

Comment: Can you please modify the Ps one liner to add two lines of text on top of each file in the concatenated file.One for adding the file name without .txt extension and other for adding the date modified or last written date to the concatenated file. ex : File name : abcd //On the next line Date : dd/mm/yyyy and then the contents of the file .

Comment: @manutd Changed as per your comment

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "delims=:" %f in ('dir *.txt /O:D /T:W /B') do @echo %f
```

This command will use `dir` to sort by oldest to newest date (`/O:D`) using the last written date (`/T:W`) and bare format (`/B`) to just return the filenames. Setting the `delims` to `:` in the `for` command keeps it from trying to parse the filename based on spaces or commas since `:` is not allowed in a filename.